# Navigate from Bar Button item to navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a view controller with bar button item, and an action on this button to navigate from the view to another navigation view controller, but when I navigate to the navigation controller the navigation bar is hidden!

my navigation code

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AdPostViewController")
    window.rootViewController = vc
    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

to clarify
I did not declare isNavigationBarhidden in the code, I am embedding a view controller to navigation controller, and when I navigate from the main view controller to the navigation controller I see the bar is hidden and I want to show it

Comment: Is `AdPostViewController` the identifier of the navigationController you want to show?

Comment: I think you should give an identifier to your nav controller and reference that rather than  `AdPostViewController` otherwise it will load your view controller without the navController/navBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to change `window.rootViewController` but to present the view controller with:

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, 
    animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

Your code become:

```
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AdPostViewController")
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edit:
And you should check if `AdPostViewController` is the identifier of the navigationController in your Storyboard.

Comment: your answer showed the navigation controller perfectly but not in a full screen, it showed it like popover @d-mika

Comment: Add `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` or modify the storyboard accordingly. (In the attribute inspector, property *Presentation*)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `isNavigationBarHidden`. Apple documented as below:

> The default value is false. Setting this property changes the visibility of the navigation bar without animating the changes. If you want to animate the change, use the setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)method instead.

Comment: this is in the destination? or the view controller that I will push from ?

Comment: you decleared "the navigation bar is hidden!" so i think in the destination

Comment: I did not declare this in the code, I am embedding a view controller to navigation controller, and when I navigate from the main view controller to the navigation controller I see the bar is hidden and I want to show it

Comment: you declared in your question.

Comment: Check out the Mika`s answer